# INSEE code for French regions?

Tags: administrative-boundaries, france

Does an INSEE code exist for French regions?
Is there a list of the official INSEE codes for French regions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The French INSEE website has a "code officiel geographique" page where you could download all code for all administrative division (in txt and dbase format)

It's at this address :
https://www.insee.fr/fr/information/2114819

For French region code look for the "Liste des régions" entry down the page

Comment: https://www.insee.fr/fr/information/2114819#titre-bloc-29 to be precise, and thanks.